# How to get a stacked histogram in PairGrid or pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, pairplot

I whish to reproduce the PairGrid plot found in [that tutorial](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/data-visualization-in-python-advanced-functionality-in-seaborn-20d217f1a9a6), but  locally my barcharts are not stacked as in the tutorial and I can't figure out how to make them so.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # for graphics
import os
os.sys.version
# '3.6.4 (default, Sep 20 2018, 19:07:50) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'

sns.__version__    
# '0.9.0'

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

g = sns.PairGrid(data=mpg[["mpg", "horsepower", "weight", "origin"]], hue="origin")
g.map_upper(sns.regplot)
g.map_lower(sns.residplot)

# below for the histogram
g.map_diag(plt.hist)

# also I tried
# g.map_diag(lambda x, label, color: plt.hist(x, label=label, color=color, histtype='barstacked', alpha=.4))
# g.map_diag(plt.hist, histtype='barstacked')
# but same result

g.savefig('./Plots/mpg.svg')
```

[image: My plots]

[image: The tutorial's plot]

Do I have to follow the second answer of this post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250843/stacked-bar-chart-using-seaborn-and-matplotlib) suggesting that it is very tricky to do with seaborn,
or should I turn to back to plt as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152279/seaborn-facetgrid-stacked-bar-chart) for a simpler chart ?

In any case I'm curious to understand how they stacked their bars in the [tutorial linked above](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/data-visualization-in-python-advanced-functionality-in-seaborn-20d217f1a9a6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option for stacked histograms on the diagonal of a PairGrid has been removed from seaborn in [this commit](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/commit/d0563d7d871d0074250540c217a33ac735f51ae5) and hence is not available anymore in seaborn 0.9.

A workaround could be to collect all the data first and then plot it to the respective axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd 

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

g = sns.PairGrid(data=df[["mpg", "horsepower", "weight", "origin"]], hue="origin")
g.map_upper(sns.regplot)
g.map_lower(sns.residplot)

# below for the histograms on the diagonal
d = {}
def func(x, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()

    if not ax in d.keys():
        d[ax] = {"data" : [], "color" : []}
    d[ax]["data"].append(x)
    d[ax]["color"].append(kwargs.get("color"))

g.map_diag(func)
for ax, dic in d.items():
    ax.hist(dic["data"], color=dic["color"], histtype="barstacked")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you

Comment: Compact and generalized to any dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Given the current version of `seaborn`, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57645960/7758804) works, but is obsolete.
- [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) has the parameter `multiple`, which has `{'layer', 'dodge', 'stack', 'fill'}` as options.

  - This can be passed to [`sns.pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) with `diag_kws={'multiple': 'stack'}`.
  - Use `g.map_diag(sns.histplot, multiple='stack')` with [`sns.PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html).
- `seaborn` doesn't offer an option for a stacked bar plot, like `pandas`. However, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804) shows how to create a stacked bar plot with `sns.histplot`.
- **Tested with `matplotlib 3.5.2` & `seaborn 0.12.0`**

#### `sns.pairplot`

```py
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
data = mpg[["mpg", "horsepower", "weight", "origin"]]

g = sns.pairplot(data=data, hue='origin', diag_kind='hist', diag_kws={'multiple': 'stack'})
```

[image]

#### `sns.PairGrid`

```py
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
data = mpg[["mpg", "horsepower", "weight", "origin"]]

g = sns.PairGrid(data=data, hue='origin')
g.map_upper(sns.regplot, scatter_kws=dict(linewidth=1, ec='white', s=20))
g.map_lower(sns.residplot, scatter_kws=dict(linewidth=1, ec='white', s=20))
_ = g.map_diag(sns.histplot, multiple='stack')
```

[image]