# How to bring back stacked histogram on seaborn pairplot after package upgrade?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, pairplot

I have pandas pairplot picture, built by the command

```
sns.pairplot(df,hue='TARGET CLASS',diag_kind='hist' )
```

[image: Before upgrade]

After package upgrade diagonal histogram changed to

[image: After upgrade]

I tried keyword argument stacked=True using python command

```
sns.pairplot(df,hue='TARGET CLASS',diag_kind='hist',**diag_kws=dict(stacked=True)**)
```

but it did not have any influence on the picture I get.
Appreciate any advice on **how I can bring the picture to its initial look**?

Comment: A review of the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) shows `multiple='stack'`

Comment: sns.pairplot(df,hue='TARGET CLASS',diag_kind='hist',multiple="stack")
gives error:
TypeError: pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multiple'

sns.pairplot(df,hue='TARGET CLASS',diag_kind='hist',diag_kws=dict(multiple="stack"))
gives:
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'multiple'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73725574/7758804 Verify your seaborn version

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Now have the problem resolved!
I restored the history how it appeared.
It happened not after direct seaborn package upgrade, but after I installed pydot

conda install pydot

I am not sure, but may be it by dependency also upgraded seaborn.
Now I updated seaborn with conda.

conda update seaborn

And it resolved the problem. diag_kws=dict(multiple="stack") option gave expected result.
[image]